# Android App launches, black screen - can hear activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app that for some reason, on the latest Android SDK (4.4) launches to a black screen.

I can still hear the activity behind it (for example if I click on somewhere in the black, a button sound is clicked, so Its almost like the screen is loaded behind the black screen).

It works fine on my device which is a Nexus 4 running 4.4, it appears to be an issue on the later version (Nexus 5) devices.

It also shows the banner ad (admob) that I have, so it literally is a case that it seems to be an issue with the background image file.

```
//@Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);        
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().setScreenSize(CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize().width, 
                CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize().height);
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDeviceOrientation(CCDirector.kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait);
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().setContentView(mGLSurfaceView, createLayoutParams());
        InitParam();
        getAdmob();
    }
```

Activity game xml is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see something abnormal in the logcat?

Comment: If the sound works in the background, then something is wrong with the Surfaceview, and the activity actual works - so it's only the display. But I'm not sure what the problem is. :|

Comment: Nothing abnormal in the logcat, could it be the size of the background image file? It is 720x1280, the actual native size of the Nexus 5 is 1080x1920, could that be the issue? Surely it would auto-stretch it to fit?

Comment: OK, appear to be getting somewhere now, if I move this line
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);`
to `super.onStart();`
Then at least I now have a background image on screen, albeit the wrong one..

Comment: If I do as above, I get the loading/splash screen only, but it stays on screen, it is TitleLayer.java that has the main menu on, for some reason that is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

width & height of the imageview is "wrap content" however the scaletype is "fitXY".
thats kind of saying 2 different things to the device.
if that image should be full screen change it's width & height to match/fill parent.

Answer (score 0):

Check onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() methods in your code, you might be doing some time consuming, blocking tasks. If so, load heavy background tasks on a separate thread.

Profile your code with [Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to check what is taking more time.